# Inheritance relationship in class diagram in java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a simple question about inheritance relationship when drawing a class diagram in java.

I have created a class that has number of attributes and methods, call it user.

Then i create 3 classes that have inheritance relationship with the parent class.
call them (customer,supplier,admin).

we know about inheritance relationship that it inherits all the attributes and methods from the parent class

I used all the attributes and methods in class customer, used all the attributes and methods in class admin but i used the attributes only in class supplier and don't need to use methods while writing my code.

is this logically correct in the world of object-oriented programming?

Comment: If you build new functionality in customer, supplier and admin or override previous functionality, then yes. Otherwise it is just pointless inheritance and code smell and also signal that there is some problem with your class hierarchy.

Comment: It's not wrong, per se, but it makes me wonder whether you have decomposed your class relationships accurately. If a subclass inherits but doesn't need something, does it really constitute an "is-a" relationship? Or do they just have some structural similarities but no logical relationship?

Comment: I used the attributes of the parent class only in my subclass but not used methods. methods are used in the other subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a reason why your supplier should not be using those methods, then you need to make another abstract class.  Below would be the hierarchy (* denotes abstract).

```
Person* -> SpecialPerson* -> Customer
Person* -> SpecialPerson* -> Admin
Person* -> Supplier
```

If at some point your supplier needs to use those methods, then you just need to simply use "extends SpecialPerson" and they will be hooked up.  It really depends on the reason why those methods are not being used.